# Skip Nginx Geographical questions Ubuntu Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, dockerfile

I'm trying to make a dockerfile with the base image ubuntu:latest and nginx on it. The problem is that everything installs perfectly but the moment Nginx gets installed it asks for a geographic area and timezone. [Screenshot Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmuGS.png)

Is there a way to someway silent install Nginx or install a version that doesn't ask these questions?

Command I use:
`apt-get install nginx -y`

The `-s` flag doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please include the Dockerfile and the command you are using to build it to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prompt for geographic location is from tzdata, you can see that from few lines before the included screenshot.

To work around the issue I added in a RUN directive:

`RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get -y install tzdata`

Now "apt-get install nginx -y" will not prompt for the geographic location.

The officila nginx image in Docker Hub has a Dockerfile with more packages installed, you may want to look for reference [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/464886ab21ebe4b036ceb36d7557bf491f6d9320/mainline/debian/Dockerfile).

Comment: Thanks @ddors! Your command was a push in the right way. Command wasn't working but after some research I found that you could do this simply:

`ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`